# Is it ok to use OpenGL 1.1?

Tags: opengl

It is ok to use functions from OpenGL 1.1 in code, for render quads with textures (for buttons) or lines (for pathes)? Functions like: glBegin, glVertex or glEnd?
P.S. For 3D models I use VBO from newer version of OpenGL.

Comment: No it's not ok. You're using something that's deprecated that has very little value. If you want more from your programs, use shaders.

Comment: Depends on what "ok" means to you. It is "ok" in the same way that using Windows 95 as a hobbyist in 2016 is "ok". However, it is definitely not a valid replacement for modern technologies in any real product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supporting compatibility profiles in OpenGL-3.3 and later is optional, so don't expect legacy functions to be available if your program also makes use of modern features. In general you should not use glBegin/glVertex/glEnd in new code. Even for pathologically simple shapes using modern OpenGL primitives will be simpler and easier to read. The only "downside" is, that you also have to specify a shader and shader setup may be a bit tedious if you're not abstracting it away.

Comment: Great answer, @datenwolf. Though, let's not forger that most of OpenGL API "upgrades" have been implemented in order to facilitate game development and take advantage of GPU processors. Much of open source code for scientific visualization, relying on `glBegin/glVertex/glEnd` CPU paradigm, which can't be ported to the `shaders` paradigm will become abandonware.

Comment: @user3078414: OpenGL-2.1 and before will not vanish. Most certainly not for the Mesa implementation (in the long term forseeable future) and also very certainly not for the vendor proprietary implementations. It's just a too important market to loose. As far as scientific visualization is concerned, especially those applications would hugely benefit from transitioning to modern OpenGL, *because* they're not that optimized as games are and reducing CPU overhead would help a lot. Vertex Arrays have been around since OpenGL-1.1 (only the were client side).

Comment: @user3078414: Recently a AMD Radeon Technology Group engineer (also responsible for their professional gear) told me about just how bad CAD software is mistreating the APIs and that, truth to be told, it would probably easier to just rewrite the rendering part for correctness and it would still be more performant than the mess currently around (not to speak of correct, which usually it is not and drivers apply a lot of internal workarounds, just to cover that).

Comment: I've also been in touch for quite some time with Nvidia engineers (I assume freedom of not disclosing names) - I could quite agree about much of CAD/CAM software mistreating the API, but it is still an object paradigm not so conceptually far from _games_ and _3D toons_. That's not what it's all about. There are many examples in scientific visualization which, having lost legacy OpenGL "primitives" support will have to migrate to commercial APIs which are not only closed source, but also more limited then pre-3.3 OpenGL. Hope I don't have to explain the consequences.